# Can you create a dynamic virtual IP (CentOS)?

Tags: networking, centos, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry Pi 2 with CentOS. I want to create multiple Proxies with different public IP's. The point is that my router doesn't have a NAT so every device I connect to my network has a different public IP. I tried creating some virtual interfaces on my RPI (with static IP). Clearly this won't work like that because I don't have any local IP and because of this the static IP would simultaneously be my public IP (ifconfig shows the same IP as any site like myip.is or ifconfig.me would show) and my ISP would first have to forward this IP. Because my ISP assigns the IP the virtual interface needs to be dynamic. I'm not sure if everything I wrote is correct because I don't know so much about networking/CentOS yet. Is it possible to create a dynamic virtual IP so that every virtual interface on my RPI has it's own different public ip?
(Sorry if my english isn't the best. My native language is german and not english)

Comment: Can you describe your configuration in which “every device I connect to my network has a different public IP.”?

Comment: Also, how those IPs are acquired (ie are they routed via another IP assigned to you), if routing us required or switching will suffice? I suspect you really need to explain exactly what you have and are trying to do, rather then assume an answer. (I wonder if you actually need policy based routing)